# How to Add objectAtIndex:i of NSArray to NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsmutabledictionary

How to Add `objectAtIndex:i` of `NSArray` to `NSMutableDictionary`

i have tried

```
for(int i=0 ;i<=[user count]; i++){

NSMutableDictionary * dict = [NSMutableDictionary :[user objectAtIndex:i]];

}
```

Comment: you can set a value with key like     NSMutableDictionary *Dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[Arr objectAtIndex:i],@"somekey", nil]

Answer (score 1):

```
 NSMutableDictionary *dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:[user count]];

 for(int i=0 ;i<[user count]; i++) {
    [dic setObject:[user objectAtIndex:i] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i]];
 }
```

Careful with this one: i<[user count], as the way you're doing it now you're going to get a message of array index out bounds. Of course, you could set the key for each element however you may want.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of for loop, use the enumerate block:

```
    NSArray *arr;
    NSMutableDictionary *dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [arr enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {

        [dic setObject:obj forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)idx]];
    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this....

```
NSArray * myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"a", @"b", @"c"];

NSDictionary * dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:myArray forKey:@"threeLetters"];

NSMutableDictionary * mutableDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:10];
[mutableDict setObject:myArray forKey:@"threeLetters"];
```